# Reading keys with square brackets in YAML files from Spring

Tags: java, spring, yaml

I have a .yml file that one of the fields looks like this

```
  a:
    b:
      "[/folder/**]": "file:./src/"
```

How can I access this field in Spring using @Value?

I tried the following but all failed with "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder"

```
@Value("${a.b./folder/**}") private File path;
```

```
@Value("${a.b.[/folder/**]}") private File path;
```

```
@Value("${a.b.\\[/folder/**\\]}") private File path;
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin:

```kotlin
@SpringBootTest
class TestExample {

    @Value("\${a.b.[/folder/**]}")
    lateinit var file: File

    @Test
    fun test() {
        // ".${File.separator}src" on Windows => .\src
        // ".${File.separator}src" on Linux => ./src
        assertEquals(".${File.separator}src", file.path)
    }
}
```

It also works with and without the "file:" prefix.

```yaml
a:
  b:
    "[/folder/**]": "./src/"
```

Comment: Is there a java solution? In java I tried: @Value("\\${a.b.[/folder/**]}") private File path, but got still got an error: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'a.b.[/folder/**]' in value "\${a.b.[/folder/**]}"

Comment: Man... @Value("\\${a.b.[/folder/**]}") not equals with @Value("\${a.b.[/folder/**]}"). Try with one "\" char. There is no ambiguity between Kotlin and Java in this area.

Comment: Unlike kotlin, @Value("\${a.b.[/folder/**]}") won't even compile in java. That's why I added one more \ at the beginning. But that still results in an error.

Comment: Look for another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your path key is in double quotes.
You must add double quotes in @Value property string like below.

```java
@Value("${a.b.\"[/folder/**]\"}")
private File path;
```

Comment: Still not working :(
Error message: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'a.b."[/folder/**]"' in value "${a.b."[/folder/**]"}"

Comment: Your value `"${a.b."[/folder/**]"}"` is different from `"${a.b.\"[/folder/**]\"}"`.   
'\' is missing in your value before double quotes.

Comment: No. I added both \ before ". Just the error message does not display that. It won't even compile if I missed the \.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a Java based project. Look. It is not complex.

[image]